# How to get name of the dropdown selected item in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i have the bookd_ids and book_titles as follows in the database:

```
 id   |  title
 ---------------
 1    |  abc
 2    |  xyz
 3    |  pqr
```

I have the books dropdownlist as show below:

```
<%=  select("books", "book_id", Book.all.collect {|b|
                [ b.title, b.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'Select Book'})%>
```

i can get the id of the books thru query this way:

```
var id = $("#books_book_id").val();
```

How to get the abc, xyz pqr titles using jquery?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var text = $("#books_book_id option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 3):

Have put some space between :`selected`

```
var value = jQuery("#edit-system-name :selected").text();
```